# Add text field using ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a text field inside a "p" tag using ng-bind-html. It is not not rendering input tags, but rendering other tags.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div ng-app="ss" ng-controller="formController">
<p ng-bind-html="hh"></p>

</div>

<script>
var myApp = angular.module("ss", ['ngSanitize']);
function formController ($scope) {
    $scope.hh="<b>Hello</b><input type='text'> ";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the output I am getting the bold text "Hello", but not the input field.

(I know I can put the text field directly in the html, but I need this for some reason)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `ngSanitize` considers `<input>` to be unsafe.
If you want to do it anyway, you must explcitly trust it:

```
.controller('formController', function ($sce, $scope) {
    $scope.hh = $sce.trustAsHtml('<b>Hello</b><input type="text" />');
}
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/pqby0nhn/)**.

---

<sub>BTW, you should properly register your controllers (using `.controller()`), because looking them up in the global object has been deprecated in the latest versions of Angular.</sub>